# Undefined name 'OnPress'

Tags: flutter, dart, null, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

OnPress method showing error. I cannot seem to initialize it or use it in the build method.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  **final Function onPress;**

  ReusableCard({@required this.colour,this.cardChild, this.onPress});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
     **onTap: OnPress,**
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it because of uppercase O in OnPress in onTap and lowercase o in Function onPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a case sensitive issue here. You need to use the same `onPress`, not `OnPress`. It will look like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress, // Here!
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```